# Убрать заполнение пространства у UI Image в unity

Tags: unity3d, svg, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Имеется большое количество svg файлов картинок с разным соотношением сторон. В юньке они настроены как Textured sprite и импортируются кодом в List. Проблема заключается в том, что когда код ставит случайный из листа спрайт с разным соотношением сторон в квадратный(по заранее выставленным настройкам) ui image, то спрайт стретчится(растягивается до формы квадрата) и выглядит это отвратно. Можно ли это как-нибудь исправить?(Mesh type в Unity стоит на Full Rect)

Один и тот же файл по разному воспринимается разными программами:
[image: illustrator]

[image: unity]

Comment: привести картинки к одному стандарту?

Comment: @AntonNikolaev у всех картинок одинаковый размер "полотна"(не знаю, как точно это назвать). Т.е. при открытии любой из них через illustrator размер фона будет одним и тем же, но unity обрезает пустые места и на выходе даёт уже спрайт с другим соотношением сторон и при добавлении его на UI Image происходит то, что я и описывал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил следующим образом:

```
transform..GetComponent<Image>().SetNativeSize();
```